# Scrolling to ID issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create smooth scrolling to `ID`s. When I click on a link its ID should be scroll to top (at a certain point of top. Ex: 200px from top) of the page.

I tried it something like this:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
      var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
      $root.animate({
          scrollTop: (($(href).offset().top >= 200 ) ? $(href).offset().top : 200)
      }, 500, function () {
          window.location.hash = href;
      });
      return false;
  });
```

But it doesn't work and its always scrolling to top of the page. 
Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: I checked it. but it doesn't work for me. That mean it scrolling to top of the page

Comment: Add your HTML code please.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, I created a demo with my html - http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/5971/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the problem is your `href`, the target will presumably not be found. Maybe you'd be better off to store the element to scroll to in a data attribute, like so:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

With an anchor tag like so:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#somewhere_over_the_rainbow">Brilliant rainbow colors</a>
```

Obviously, the element with the ID `somewhere_over_the_rainbow` must exist somewhere in your DOM.

Comment: Jan, I checked with your code. But it again scroll to top. Actually I need to stop scroll at a certain point of the top.

Comment: I changed this `scrollTop: $(target).offset().top` to  `scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 100` and got it to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job correctly :

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {

 var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
 var top = $(href).offset().top;
 $('body').animate(
    {
     scrollTop: top - 200
    },
    500
 );
 return false;
});
```

Obviously, the item with the id equal to the hash of the anchor must exist.

Comment: I checked, it stop scroll now

Comment: No. scroll is not happen now.